# Maximize/minimize the dimension of a space of matrices that commute with a certain matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

For $n \times n$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$, $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ define $U(\mathbf{A})$, $W(\mathbf{A}, v)$ as
$$U(\mathbf{A}) = \{ \mathbf{X} \in \text{Mat}_n(\mathbb{R}) | \mathbf{A}\mathbf{X} =\mathbf{X}\mathbf{A} \}
\\
W(\mathbf{A}, v) = \langle v, \mathbf{A}v, \mathbf{A}^2v, \mathbf{A}^3v,\cdots\rangle
$$

1. Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a matrix such that $\text{dim}\space W(\mathbf{A}, v)=n$ for every $v \neq 0$. Find $\underset{\mathbf{A}}{\max}\text{dim} \space U(\mathbf{A})$.
2. Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a matrix such that $\text{dim} \space W(\mathbf{A}, v) < n$ for every $v$. Find $\underset{\mathbf{A}}{\min}\text{dim} \space U(\mathbf{A})$.

For the first part, it seems that the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ has no real eigenvalues. It is clear that matrix $\mathbf{A}$ commutes with any polynomial $p(\mathbf{A})$. At this point, I'm stuck and don't know how to proceed and solve this.

Comment: In the terminology of Hoffman and Kunze's *Linear Algebra*, we could say that a matrix $A$ satisfying the conditions for part 1 must be such that every $A$-cyclic subspace is also $A$-admissible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** For part 1, $n$ must be even and $A$ must be similar to the [Real Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices) matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{C&I\\&C&\ddots\\&&\ddots&I\\&&&C}
$$
for some $C = \left[ \begin{smallmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. Equivalently, $A$ is similar to the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of the polynomial $p(x) = [(x-a)^2 + b^2]^n$. Because $A$ is similar to a companion matrix (i.e. is "non-derogatory" in the terminology of Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis*), we can deduce that $A$ commutes with $B$ if and only if $B = p(A)$.

For a final answer, you should end up with $n$. The "maximum" in this case is trivial because $\dim U(A)$ is completely determined.

For part 2, we can only deduce that the degree of the minimal polynomial of $A$ is strictly less than $n$. Equivalently, $A$ necessarily has a (possibly complex) eigenspace of dimension $2$ or greater.

For a final answer, you should end up with $n + 2$.